# Create Access report that lists information from one table, which is matched on ID from another table

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I'm updating this as the previous answer turned out to not be what I really needed.

I have two tables in my Access database. One is called Billings, one is called Bookings. Each table has a column called Booking Number, which is how they are related. The Billings table also has a field called Container. What I want to do is:

- Create a one page report for each Booking Number (which can be expanded to multiple pages depending on the number of containers)
- In the body of the report I would like to list each Container (along with other information about each container) on separate rows

Here are my tables:

```
Bookings
----------------
ID | Booking Number
 1 | '1234'
 2 | '1235'


Billings
----------------
ID | Booking Number | Container
 1 | '1234'         | '12'
 2 | '1234'         | '16'
 3 | '1235'         | '18'
```

Based on these two tables, there should be a report for Booking #1234, and Booking #1235. Booking #1234's report should list Container's 12 and 16, while Booking #1235's report would only list 18. I'm a PHP/MySQL developer, so I understand SQL queries. However, the way I would write the query for MySQL obviously does not work for Access. At the moment I am using a Module similar to the answer below, but it does not do what I need it to do. This is my current query:

```
SELECT
    b.*,
    ListContainers(b.[Booking Number]) AS Containers
FROM
    Bookings AS b
WHERE
    ((b.[Booking Number]) Is Not Null);
```

This will create a comma separated list of the containers associated with each Booking Number, but I want to create a separate row for each Container, which will also include other information from the Billings table.

Has anyone had any experience with a similar situation, or know any steps I could take to accomplish what I'm looking to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your new requirements you'll want to use a "subreport" to list the containers (and related information). For details, see my recent answer to a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16242899/passing-query-parameter-to-sub-report/16251417#16251417).

Comment: You're awesome, Gord. I apologize for the unaccept earlier. If I could accept both answers I would. Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

[This is my answer to the original question, before the "spec" changed.]

Create a new `Module` in Access and paste in the following code

```
Public Function ListContainers(Booking_Number As String) As String
Dim cdb As DAO.Database, rst As DAO.Recordset, rtn As String
Const Separator = ", "
Set cdb = CurrentDb
rtn = ""
Set rst = cdb.OpenRecordset("SELECT Container FROM Billings WHERE [Booking Number]=""" & Booking_Number & """ ORDER BY Container", dbOpenSnapshot)
Do While Not rst.EOF
    rtn = rtn & rst!Container & Separator
    rst.MoveNext
Loop
rst.Close
Set rst = Nothing
Set cdb = Nothing
If Len(rtn) > 0 Then
    rtn = Left(rtn, Len(rtn) - Len(Separator))  '' trim trailing separator
End If
ListContainers = rtn
End Function
```

You can then use that Function in a query, like this

```
SELECT [Booking Number], ListContainers([Booking Number]) AS Containers
FROM Billings
```

That will return

```
Booking Number  Containers
--------------  ----------
1234            12, 16
1235            18
```

Comment: Thank you, Gord! I modified it just a bit to include some other info that I need for the report, but this is exactly what I was looking for. Much appreciated!