# Passing Query Parameter to Sub-Report

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, vba

It has been a long time since I have worked with MS Access and am not sure if I am doing this right.

I have a Report bound to a query of single list of user names. The report groups on the user name and has a sub-report in the detail that is a chart.

The sub-report/chart is based on a query that accepts a parameter of the user name. Since the sub report is not bound I need to pass the user name parameter from the main report detail onload event down to the sub-report and thus into the underlying query.

I am not understanding how to make that happen or even if my approach is sound.

(p.s. i originally posted on "Super User" but see not many people use that site.)

Thanks for the help

Comment: When you say that the subreport is "not bound" do you mean that the Subform/Subreport control has no values for `Link Master Fields` and `Link Child Fields`?

Comment: Yes it is not bound.  Those fields cannot be set in the property window.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To get the full benefit of subreports they should be bound to a recordsource (table or query) and use the `Link Master Fields` and `Link Child Fields` properties of the Subform/Subreport control to "sync" the subreport data with the parent record.

Say you have a [Users] table

```
userID
------
Gord
Tim
```

and a [UserTraffic] table

```
userID  trafficDate downloadMB
------  ----------- ----------
Gord    2013-04-26  366
Gord    2013-04-25  442
Tim     2013-04-26  890
Tim     2013-04-25  212
```

Your main report [UserReport] is bound to [Users] and contains a subreport control based on the report [UserTraffic_subreport]

[image: subreport1.png]

When you use that report in your Subform/Subreport control on your main form...

[image: mainreport.png]

...be sure to set the `Link Master Fields` and `Link Child Fields` properties...

[image: properties.png]

...so your report will come out like this:

[image: preview.png]

Note that this example required no VBA code at all.

### Edit

The same principles apply when adding a chart to a report. The following report displays user traffic by date, so the Record Source for the main report is

```
SELECT DISTINCT trafficDate FROM UserTraffic ORDER BY trafficDate;
```

The report uses a Chart control instead of the Subform/Subreport control...

[image: design.png]

...and the properties of the Chart control are...

[image: properties.png]

The resulting report looks like this

[image: preview.png]

Comment: This is a superb response and much appreciated. I my case I am struggling with a Chart as the sub report.  The chart wizard throws me because it wants row source info.  Ultimately, I want one report with a chart for Gord, Tim and anyone in the Users table in your example.  I still cannot configure this up.  Thanks again Gord!

Comment: The only difference between your report and mine is that I am using a cross-tab query as the source of the chart.  The source query of chart has a parameter of user name.  The user name is not displayed in the query it thus rendering the link master/child unavailable on report designer. The main report has  data source of the  users so each record of report is a user.  The user name needs to go to the report somehow so the proper chart shows up.  Again... not sure if I am even approaching this correctly.  Much appreciate the patience and help.

Comment: I think i need to dynamically alter the rowsource SQL statement on each record.  Probably on the onprint & onpaint events.

Comment: @ChiliYago Is the sole purpose of the query parameter to isolate the records for a single user? If so, you might be able to alter the query so it returns results for all users and includes the user name as an additional column so the Master/Child relationship can be established.

Comment: Yes that is correct.  The parameter to the query isolates the data to the user.  I am not having much luck changing the graph's rowsource property be event. Seems like the code runs but the graphs on each record is the same.  I'll see if I can make it work your way.