# MS Access custom layout report

Tags: ms-access, foreach, report, customization, record

Currently I have a query that returns records like this:

```
ChargeCode     Type        Price
THC            Credit      6200
OTH            Debit       3000
THC            Debit       5400
```

Then i need to generate a report for it. I do not want the report to show as follows

```
Debit     ChargeCode        Credit
5400      THC               6200
3000      OTH
```

How can I do it? I can not find any way to have Access allow us to customize how we output for each record. Or we have the main query that output the charge code, then the left col will do the query based on received charge code and type="debit", the right col will do the query based on received charge code and type="credit"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really understand your concern. If it's the order of the columns that bothers you, then the query...

```
TRANSFORM Sum(Charges.[Price]) AS SumOfPrice
SELECT Charges.[ChargeCode]
FROM Charges
GROUP BY Charges.[ChargeCode]
PIVOT Charges.[Type] In ("Debit","Credit");
```

...will produce the following result:

```
ChargeCode  Debit  Credit
----------  -----  ------
OTH          3000         
THC          5400    6200
```

You can then create a report using that query as its Record Source, but when you create the Report you can specify the columns in whatever order you prefer, anyway.

Comment: Thanks for your response.. I understand what you mean, but say, what i really want to know is that is it possible if in a report, I use 2 or more queries, which one main query will return a set of data, and for each record, i will use some of them to output and some of them as parameters for other query? I tried to search for report with store procedure or function (something like that) but still no clue :(

Comment: @user2273827 That sounds very similar to a qustion I answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16242899/passing-query-parameter-to-sub-report/16251417#16251417). Using a Subreport is one way of achieving that.

Comment: Thanks a lot Mr.Gord Thompson, your suggestions about subreport and pivot are very useful for me.. I think that I can base on them to solve my problem :)