# Creating Charts using recordset in MS Access 2010

Tags: ms-access, charts, vba, ms-access-2010

I have never created a chart in an MS Access 2010 form before and would like to ask anyone if they have a code to create 1. ill be basing the information that will be placed inside the chart via recordset if possible.

```
dim db as dao.database
dim rs as dao.recordset
dim strsql as string
dim AMOGraph as object


set db = currentdb()

strsql = "Select * [column1] From Table1 WHERE [Column1] = '" & a & "'"

set rs = db.openrecordset(strsql)
```

im stuck here... is it possible to create a chart(bar) from here? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You might find [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16251417/2144390) helpful. The first part deals with subreports, but the second part (after the **Edit**) talks about charts.

Answer (score 0):

Answer was staring me right in the face..

```
with Forms![Graph1}
    .rowsource = "Select * From Blah"
    .requery
end with
```