# Passing Query Parameter to Sub-Form

Tags: database, ms-access, ms-access-2007, ms-access-2010

I've read many other questions which are similar in nature but mine needs something a little bit different and I am struggling.

(This solution is great but I need something extra on top of it: [Passing Query Parameter to Sub-Report](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16242899/passing-query-parameter-to-sub-report))

I have 2 tables: Events and Comments. 
My main form is bound to Events which contains a subform that is based off a query that has a parameter (eID = the event ID). Basically, the subform shows all the comments (like a log) for a specific Event.

I tried to use the masterlink/childlink...and I get this error

> You must add field cEvent to your record source if you wish to use this link.

**(FYI : Comments.cEvent = Events.eID)**

PROBLEM: It seems like it wants me to include the cEvents so the subform can rendor all the comments for all the Events organized by tabs... but I just want the comments for this particular Event and that's it.

Comment: Can we see the query?

Comment: Query for the Comments: `PARAMETERS [Enter Event] Short;
SELECT Comments.CDate, Comments.cComment
FROM Comments
WHERE (((Comments.cEvent)=[Enter Event]));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you've got it mixed up.

Your master query should look like this:

```
PARAMETERS [Enter Event] Long; 
SELECT *
FROM Events 
WHERE eId=[Enter Event];
```

then the child query could be:

```
SELECT Comments.cEvent, Comments.CDate, Comments.cComment 
FROM Comments;
```

The Master/Child setting will take care of the filtering of the subform.

Comment: Thanks that works great! My problem was creating a parameter for the child query, when the master/child setting will take care of it for me. !! :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if I fully understand, but does this help? On the main form you would put a combo box to select which Event you are interested in and the sub form then shows only the data from the related comments.

```
SELECT Comments.CDate, Comments.cComment, Comments.cEvent, Comments.EventsLookup
FROM Comments
WHERE (((Comments.EventsLookup)=[Forms]![frmMain]![ID]));
```